# How do I obtain the frequency of strings of a given list in another bigger list of strings in R?

Tags: python, r

I have the following code in python :

```
# most popular language list 

programing_language_list = ['python', 'java', 'c++', 'php', 'javascript', 'objective-c', 'ruby', 'perl','c','c#', 'sql','kotlin']

# get our Minimum Qualifications column and convert all of the values to a list

minimum_qualifications = df_job_skills['Minimum Qualifications'].tolist()

# let's join our list to a single string and lower case the letter

miniumum_qualifications_string = "".join(str(v) for v in minimum_qualifications).lower()

# find out which language occurs in most in minimum Qualifications string

wordcount = dict((x,0) for x in programing_language_list)
for w in re.findall(r"[\w'+#-]+|[.!?;’]", miniumum_qualifications_string):
    if w in wordcount:
       wordcount[w] += 1
```

Now I want to do the same in R which I have attempted to do this way:

```
# most popular language list 

programing_language_list = list('python', 'java', 'c++', 'php', 'javascript', 'objective-c', 'ruby', 'perl','c','c#', 'sql','kotlin')
#match(c('python',),programing_language_list)

# get our Minimum Qualifications column and convert all of the values to a list

minimum_qualifications = list(dataset[,6])

# let's join our list to a single string and lower case the letter

miniumum_qualifications_string = sapply(paste(unlist(minimum_qualifications),sep=', ',collapse = ""),tolower)

#install.packages("stringr")

library(stringr)

# find out which language occurs in most in minimum Qualifications string


res_min = regmatches(miniumum_qualifications_string,gregexpr("[\\w'+#-]+|[.!?;']",miniumum_qualifications_string,perl = TRUE))
```

In the absence of dict in R, I have attempted to do it in a round about way like this:

```
k=0
for( w in res_min)
{
  for(i in programing_language_list)
  {

      if(i == w) 
      {
        j[k]=i
        print(j[k])
        k=k+1
      }
  }
}
```

But his shows an output like this:

Warning messages:

```
1: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
2: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
3: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
4: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
5: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
6: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
7: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
8: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
9: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
10: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
11: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
12: In if (i == w) { ... :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Now my intention is to find the frequencies of the strings of

> programing_language_list

in

> res_min

and my intention is to obtain a

> dict

like data structure as in Python and obtain a 12 × 2 matrix like data structure where it will have in its first column the strings like

> "Python", "C++"

And in the second column it will have counts of the same strings in the list

> res_min

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Here is the dataset url:

https://www.kaggle.com/niyamatalmass/google-job-skills

Comment: @akrun I believe I asked how I could find out the frequencies of those strings in a second list called res_min as asked in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed that `dataset[,6]` is not showed here nor is `df_job_skills`

Comment: @akrun The issue is not about that particular column which is nothing but a column of approximately 8400 strings where each row has approx. 70-80 strings. I have already converted the whole column into a single string following which I created a list of all those strings which is my res_min. This res_min is the list where I have to find out the strings that are already in programming_language list and obtain each string's frequency.

Comment: Ok then I will give you the dataset.

Comment: We don't need the 8400 strings, just a subset of may be 20-30 that runs your code in python and R

Comment: Ok I will give it

Comment: Are `res_min` and `programing_language_list` both vectors? If one of them is a list of vectors, the `if(i == w)` would try to match a single string with a vector, which `if` cannot handle. In this case, `if(i %in% w)` should work.

Comment: @LAP Both lists. Yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be a mistake in generating `miniumum_qualifications_string`.

Using `sep = ", ", collapse = ""` does basically nothing. You just need `collapse = ","`.

Example:

```
set.seed(1)
programing_language_list = list('python', 'java', 'c++', 'php', 'javascript', 'objective-c', 'ruby', 'perl','c','c#', 'sql','kotlin')
minimum_qualifications <- sample(programing_language_list, 10, replace = T)
```

Now your `paste` creates this:

```
miniumum_qualifications_string = sapply(paste(unlist(minimum_qualifications),sep=', ',collapse = ""),tolower)

  phpjavascriptrubysqlc++sqlkotlinperlperlpython 
"phpjavascriptrubysqlc++sqlkotlinperlperlpython"
```

Whereas

```
miniumum_qualifications_string = sapply(paste(unlist(minimum_qualifications), collapse = ","),tolower)
```

outputs the correct separated string:

```
 php,javascript,ruby,sql,c++,sql,kotlin,perl,perl,python 
"php,javascript,ruby,sql,c++,sql,kotlin,perl,perl,python"
```

which then can be further modified by `regmatches`:

```
res_min = regmatches(miniumum_qualifications_string,gregexpr("[\\w'+#-]+|[.!?;']",miniumum_qualifications_string,perl = TRUE))

$`php,javascript,ruby,sql,c++,sql,kotlin,perl,perl,python`
 [1] "php"        "javascript" "ruby"       "sql"        "c++"        "sql"        "kotlin"     "perl"       "perl"       "python"
```

Now because `regmatches` outputs a list, you need to `unlist` it to work with your `for` loop:

```
k=0
j <- vector("character", 0)
for( w in unlist(res_min))
{
  for(i in programing_language_list)
  {

    if(i == w) 
    {
      j[k]=i
      print(j[k])
      k=k+1
    }
  }
} 

[1] "javascript"
[1] "ruby"
[1] "sql"
[1] "c++"
[1] "sql"
[1] "kotlin"
[1] "perl"
[1] "perl"
[1] "python"

> k
[1] 10

> j
[1] "javascript" "ruby"       "sql"        "c++"        "sql"        "kotlin"     "perl"       "perl"       "python"
```

Answer (score 0):

# most popular language list

```
programing_language_list = list('python', 'java', 'c++', 'php', 'javascript', 'objective-c', 'ruby', 'perl','c','c#', 'sql','kotlin')
#match(c('python',),programing_language_list)

# get our Minimum Qualifications column and convert all of the values to a list

minimum_qualifications = list(dataset[,6])

# let's join our list to a single string and lower case the letter

miniumum_qualifications_string = sapply(paste(unlist(minimum_qualifications),sep=', ',collapse = ""),tolower)

#install.packages("stringr")

library(stringr)

# find out which language occurs in most in minimum Qualifications string


res_min = regmatches(miniumum_qualifications_string,gregexpr("[\\w'+#-]+|[.!?;']",miniumum_qualifications_string,perl = TRUE))

# this is the frequency table of the list res_min
res_min2=table(res_min)
res_min2=sort(res_min2, decreasing = TRUE)
programming_language_table[1,2]=res_min2["python"]
programming_language_table[2,2]=res_min2["java"]
programming_language_table[3,2]=res_min2["c++"]
programming_language_table[4,2]=res_min2["php"]
programming_language_table[5,2]=res_min2["javascript"]
programming_language_table[6,2]=res_min2["objective-c"]
programming_language_table[7,2]=res_min2["ruby"]
programming_language_table[8,2]=res_min2["perl"]
programming_language_table[9,2]=res_min2["c"]
programming_language_table[10,2]=res_min2["c#"]
programming_language_table[11,2]=res_min2["sql"]
programming_language_table[12,2]=res_min2["kotlin"]

programming_language_table=programming_language_table[order(- 
programming_language_table$no_of_counts),]
```

Output is :

```
python       97

javascript   77

java         76

sql          73

c++          54

c            17

c#           15

ruby         14

php           7

perl          6

objective-c   3

kotlin        3
```